# Get HTTP GET parameters from Restlet request

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am trying to figure out how to get the parameters from a Restlet request object.

my request comes in as /customer?userId=1 and I want to grab the parameter to pass to my DAO for the query.

```
public class CustomerResource extends ServerResource
{
  @Get("xml")
  public Representation toXml() throws ResourceException, Exception
  {
      try
      {
          //get param from request
         //call DAO with parameter
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          throw e;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I figured it out....

```
public class CustomerResource extends ServerResource
{
  @Get("xml")
  public Representation toXml() throws ResourceException, Exception
  {
      try
      {
          //get param from request
          getQuery().getValues("userId")
         //call DAO with parameter
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          throw e;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It was hard for me to figure it out too.

Comment: Its 2014 and I still felt hard to figure this out :) Thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 8):

Please not that there is a shortcut method for that:

```
String paramValue = getQueryValue("userId");
```

Hope it helps you.